# Problems with ATI's driver (weird glitches and screenshots not working)

Tags: linux-mint, ati-mobility-radeon, fglrx

I have a problem with fglrx, it's 3 things:
It's slow, really slow (2800-/+fps in glxgears, in Fedora 17 it used to be about 7-8k)
Weird glitches sometimes appear on the screen, when launching apps like steam and such, and steam icon doesn't show up
Screenshots work in a weird way, screen flashes, looks like it took screenshot, image appears but it doesn't have the **actual** desktop image on it, just a random one from X minutes ago

ATI Mobility HD 5470
Mint 14 Nadia x64 with Cinnamon, 13.1 driver from AMD site

Answer (score 1):

I have the same screenshot problem in Mint 13 x64 with Cinnamon.  If [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1080002) is the same issue, then it appears, "This is caused by AMD's proprietary driver. There's nothing [Ubuntu] can do about it."

Not sure what driver version, but I installed it from the package repos, not from AMD.  Here's a workaround I just found that has worked for several screenshots in a row: switch to a text-mode virtual terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F1 on my system), then back to X11 (Alt-F8 or maybe F7/F9).  If I take the screenshot right after that, I get the correct screen contents.  Once I switch windows or something, it seems pretty reliable that I get old contents.

If it makes a difference, I was using Ctrl-Shift-PrtScreen (allows you to select an area to crop to, and copies to the clipboard instead of to a file) for most tests, but just verified PrtScreen alone seems to also work with this.